# mysql multiple group_concat order preservation

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

let's say I have a table **mytable**:

`select * from mytable`:

`+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | a    |
|    1 |    2 | b    |
+------+------+------+`

I want to group both the columns **b** and **c** with `group_concat` function:

`select a, group_concat(b), group_concat(c) from mytable group by a`

`+------+-----------------+-----------------+
| a    | group_concat(b) | group_concat(c) |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 1,2             | a,b             |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+`

My question is, do the mysql guarantee, that the `group_concat` will be always in the same order, that I won't get results like **1, 2** in the second column and **b, a** in the third column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an `ORDER BY` clause inside the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT a, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(b ORDER BY b), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c ORDER BY c)
FROM mytable GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 4):

Without specifying a `order by` the orders are not guaranteed and that's the same reason `group_concat()` has it's own `order by clause`. Per MySQL Spec, the syntax is as below

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

so if you want to be sure about the order then specify a `order by` like

```
select a, 
group_concat(b order by b desc) as b_concat, 
group_concat(c order by c desc) as c_concat
from mytable 
group by a
```